# Response is not available in this context?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Response is not available in context? How to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586201/response-is-not-available-in-context-how-to-solve-it)

I want to sent a pdf file to client as attachement. I try to use Response object to achieve it. But come up with error.

```
Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();

            //Set the appropriate ContentType.
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+Server.MapPath(@".\test.pdf"));
            Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";

            //Write the pdfStream into Response
            Response.BinaryWrite(pdfData);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

But always throw the "Response is not available in this context". If anyone can help me?

PS:I save a pdf file as stream(pdfData).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, well, what is the context?  Where is this code running?

Comment: Where are you running this code. In an asp.net page?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use HttpContext.Current.Response in a code location where there is no current response.

If this is used in an HTTPHandler, you need to use the Context object passed through the ProcessRequest method in the IHTTPHandler interface.