# Getting error while redirecting 'Response is not available in this context'

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am using following code to redirect user to a page.

```
Session["USERDATA"] = user;
if (roleName.Equals("Zerker", StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
   Response.Redirect("~/Account/Dashboard.aspx");
```

but this causing the error.

> *Response is not available in this context.*

What should I do?

Comment: Please check the file path in server.transfer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586201/response-is-not-available-in-context-how-to-solve-it

Comment: Use Server.Transfer instead of Response.Redirect and then check.

Comment: But Server.Transfer will not change the URL that I want.

Comment: Before response.redirect check if(this.Context!=null){Response.Redirect("~/Account/Dashboard.aspx");}

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think you are using response object in your own class. This object will not be available there.

Try using

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Dashboard.aspx");
```

Comment: I got this error when I put it in my `Global.asax`.
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`