# how to redirect on session expired event from global.aspx

Tags: session, redirect, session-state, session-timeout, global-asax

i am calling a method on session end in global.aspx file as fallow

```
SqlDBHelper objSearch = new SqlDBHelper();
if (objSearch.ExecuteNonQuery("UPDATE Supplier SET Login_Status = 0 WHERE Supp_Id =" + Session["SuppID"]))
{
    Response.Redirect("Supp_Dashboard.aspx");
    //Supp_Dashboard.aspx for l
}
```

but on

```
Response.Redirect("Supp_Dashboard.aspx");
```

it gives the error i have use the same code elsewhere there it working fine. i do not understand what is the problem..

Comment: session_end is not triggered by a user request. It happens upon timeout. There is no response to redirect at that time.

Comment: then how to redirect is there any alternative

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516241/getting-error-while-redirecting-response-is-not-available-in-this-context

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1439432.aspx

Comment: You do not need to (and can't anyway) redirect at that moment. The last post of your second comment gives an interesting solution for client redirecting.

Comment: Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", Convert.ToString(Session.Timeout * 60) +"; URL=SessionExpPage.aspx");

will redirect the page but the i have to reset the flag then redirect

Comment: is that fire at the same time

Comment: No it won't fire at the same time (and, if your user navigates in several tabs, it may fire when it should not)